# Query to return one record when pivot table has exactly one record for each id in the IN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

**users**:

```
id       username
-----------------
1        user1                    
2        user2                    
3        user3
```

**chats**:

```
id      created_on
---------------------------
1       2020-11-07 00:00:00
2       2020-11-08 00:00:00
```

**chat_users** (pivot):

```
id      chat_id      user_id
----------------------------
1       1            1
2       1            2
3       2            1
4       2            2
5       2            3
```

Given an array of user ids, i want to return one `chat` record or an empty result.
Examples:

1. Given user ids (1, 2), return chat row with id 1.
2. Given user ids (1, 3), return an empty result set.
3. Given user ids (1, 2, 3), return chat row with id 2.

I've tried something like:

```
select distinct c.*
from chats as c
  join chat_users as cu on cu.user_id in (...)
;
```

but I know that's not right and it doesn't work for matching the pivot records exactly.

Thank you in advance - any help is much appreciated, I'm drawing a blank.

**UPDATE**

This seems to work, but I have a feeling it is a less than ideal solution:

```
with filtered_chat_users as (
    select cu.chat_id, string_agg(cu.user_id::text, ',' order by cu.user_id asc) as user_ids
    from chat_users as cu 
    where cu.user_id in (1, 2, 3)
    group by cu.chat_id
)
select c.*
from filtered_chat_users as fcu
    join chats as c on c.id = fcu.chat_id
where fcu.user_ids = '1,2,3';
```

**UDPATE 2:**
The above does not work as I had thought/hoped. Passing in a subset of user ids incorrectly matches on chat records: passing in (1, 2) returns both chats 1 and 2.

**UPDATE 3:**

This *does* work, but again wondering if there is a more efficient solution:

```
with filtered_chats as (
    select distinct c.id
    from chats as c
        join chat_users as cu on cu.chat_id = c.id
            and cu.user_id in (1, 2)
), filtered_chat_users as (
    select cu.chat_id, string_agg(cu.user_id::text, ',' order by cu.user_id asc) as user_ids
    from chat_users as cu
        join filtered_chats as fc on fc.id = cu.chat_id
    group by cu.chat_id
)
select c.*
from filtered_chat_users as fcu
    join chats as c on c.id = fcu.chat_id
where fcu.user_ids = '1,2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select chat_id
from chat_users cu
group by chat_id
having count(*) filter (user_id in (1, 2, 3)) = count(*) and
       count(*) = 3;
```

The list and "3" need to change depending on what you are looking for.

This checks that all specified users are in the chat.  The `= 3` validates that only those users are there.